# How to show different span based on radio button selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am trying to display a specific span message based on a radio button selection. In addition, I want to lock the selection as soon as the user made the choice. So in other words:

[image]

I was able to almost achieve this effect that I'm trying to create:
http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/HkFXs/1/

But I'm not sure how to make the incorrect part display upon selection for an incorrect option. I'm still a beginner programmer and not sure how to make it work. Please see my JS and HTML below. Would appreciate insight on how to make this work!

HTML

```
      <div id="wizard">



        <div id="space" style="width:810px; background:white; height:10px;">
        </div>

        <div class="items">

            <!-- Question 1 -->
            <div class="page one">
                <h2><strong>Question 1:</strong></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li class="required double">
                        <label>
                            <div class="qselections required">
                                <input type="radio" value="a" name="question1">a) New York
                                <div id="questiononea"></div>
                                <br>
                                <input type="radio" value="b" name="question1">b) Washington DC
                                <br>
                                <input type="radio" value="c" name="question1">c) Seattle
                                <br>
                                <input type="radio" value="d" name="question1">d) Portland
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" class="next right">Proceed »</button>
                </li>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div><!--items-->

      </div><!--wizard-->

    </form>
```

JavaScript

```
    $(function () {



      var root = $("#wizard").scrollable();
      var isRadioCheck = false;
      // some variables that we need
      var api = root.scrollable(),
          drawer = $("#drawer");


          // prevent the user from making another selection once one radio option has been selected
        $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){ $('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled',true); });

          // Show user correct answer
        var appended = " <span id='qselectionsCORRECT' style='font-size:16px; line-height:16px;'>Correct</span>";
        appended.id = 'appended';

        $('input:radio[name="question1"]').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val() == 'a') {
                    $(appended).appendTo('#questiononea');
                }
                else {
                    $(appended).remove();
                }
            });

      // validation logic is done inside the onBeforeSeek callback
      api.onBeforeSeek(function (event, i) {

          // we are going 1 step backwards so no need for validation
          if (api.getIndex() < i || $('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) {

              // 1. get current page
              var page = root.find(".page,.qselections").eq(api.getIndex()),

                  // 2. .. and all required fields inside the page
                  inputs = page.find(".required :input").removeClass("error"),

                  // 3. .. which are empty
                  empty = inputs.filter(function () {
                      isRadioCheck = $('input[type=radio]').is(':checked');
                      return $(this).val().replace(/\s*/g, '') == '';
                  });



              //ealert('Empty Value is bool : ' + empty.length + isRadioCheck);
              if (isRadioCheck) {
                  $('.qselections').removeClass("error");
                  //alert('removed');
              }
              // if there are empty fields, then
              if (empty.length || !isRadioCheck) {

                  // slide down the drawer
                  drawer.slideDown(function () {

                      // colored flash effect
                      drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#fff");
                      setTimeout(function () {
                          drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#fff");
                      }, 1000);
                  });

                  // add a CSS class name "error" for empty & required fields
                  empty.addClass("error");
                  if (!isRadioCheck) $('.qselections').addClass("error");
                  // cancel seeking of the scrollable by returning false
                  return false;

                  // everything is good
              } else {

                  // hide the drawer
                  drawer.slideUp();
              }

          }

          // update status bar
          $("#status li").removeClass("active").eq(i).addClass("active");

      });

      // if tab is pressed on the next button seek to next page
      root.find("button.next").keydown(function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 9) {

              // seeks to next tab by executing our validation routine
              api.next();
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      });
    });
```

But

Comment: What do you mean by "lock the selection"? What needs to happen?

Comment: Hey sorry about the confusion. Meaning that if a user selects (clicks on) a radio button, say the first one, he won't be able to change his answer and then select the second one. Does that make sense? I was able to achieve that part. Take a look at the jsFiddle and try to make a selection. Then select another one. That's what I meant :).

Answer (score 1):

Why not fix it with CSS? With javascript just add a true/false (or something else) class to your inputs, like this:

```
  <input type="radio" value="a" class="true" />
  <input type="radio" value="b" class="false" />
```

And with CSS, use the :after-pseudo

```
input.true:after {
    content:'Correct';
    color:green;
}
input.false:after {
    content:'Incorrect';
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @meavo - can you please show me on Jsfiddle how this would work? I tried and can't get it to work.

Comment: For example http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=rRRBt377gw. I've wrapped a label around the radiobox and a span around the text you'd normally use a a label. This is just the CSS part, I didn't do any JS in the fiddle, but you can easily implement it in your logic by just toggling a class on the necessary labels.